# Channel Images and Channel Form

Tags: ee2, devdemon, channel-images

Am using the following code for channel images field to be displayed on the frontend using channel form tag.

```
<label for="ad_uploads">Upload your images</label>
{field:ad_uploads}
```

However, it doesn't work!

Any suggestions?

Am using ee 2.11.3 and Channel images 6.0.2

Answer (score 0):

If this is still actual, please choose the variant which is best matched to your needs:

1) switch on the Channel form (or Safecracker form) "include_assets" and "include_jquery" parameters:

```
{exp:channel:form
  channel="some_channel"
  ...
  include_assets="yes"
  include_jquery="yes"
  ...
}
```

2) in a case if you would like to use some custom version of jQuery, then switch off these parameters.

```
{exp:channel:form
  channel="some_channel"
  ...
  include_assets="no"
  include_jquery="no"
  ...
}
```

However, in the second variant you have to update your layout with:

1) jQuery loading script;

2) all the scripts needed to run Channel Images including jQuery-UI, handlebars etc.;

3) embed the EE {csrf_token} tag to the scripts (see below).

It should look something like that:

```
  <script src="/bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <!-- channel images functions-->
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    if (typeof EE == "undefined" || ! EE) { 
      var EE = {"publish":{"title_focus":false,"smileys":false,"url_title_prefix":"","default_entry_title":""},"user_id":"7","lang":{"confirm_exit":"When you leave, any data entered will be lost. Are you sure you want to leave?","add_new_html_button":"Add New HTML button"},"XID":"{csrf_token}","CSRF_TOKEN":"{csrf_token}"};
    }
    EE.grid_cache = [];

    window.Grid = {
      bind: function() {
        EE.grid_cache.push(arguments);
      }
    };
    mySettings = {
      "nameSpace":"html","onShiftEnter":{"keepDefault":false,"replaceWith":"<br \/>\n"},"onCtrlEnter":{"keepDefault":false,"openWith":"\n<p>","closeWith":"<\/p>\n"},"markupSet":[{"name":"html_btn_bold","key":"B","openWith":"<strong>","closeWith":"<\/strong>","className":"html-bold"},{"name":"html_btn_italic","key":"I","openWith":"<em>","closeWith":"<\/em>","className":"html-italic"},{"name":"html_btn_blockquote","key":"Q","openWith":"<blockquote>","closeWith":"<\/blockquote>","className":"html-quote"},{"name":"html_btn_anchor","key":"A","openWith":"<a href=\"[![Link:!:http:\/\/]!]\"(!( title=\"[![Title]!]\")!)>","closeWith":"<\/a>","className":"html-link"},{"name":"html_btn_picture","key":"","openWith":"<img src=\"[![Link:!:http:\/\/]!]\" alt=\"[![Alternative text]!]\" \/>","closeWith":"","className":"html-upload"}]
    };
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript"> var ChannelImages = ChannelImages ? ChannelImages : {};
    ChannelImages.AJAX_URL = '//your_site.com/?ACT=28&site_id=1';
    ChannelImages.THEME_URL = '//your_site.com/themes/user/channel_images/';
    ChannelImages.site_id = '1';
  </script>

  <script src="//your_site.com/themes/user/channel_images/js/handlebars.runtime-v4.js?v=6.0.2" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//your_site.com/themes/user/channel_images/js/hbs-templates.js?v=6.0.2" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="//your_site.com/themes/user/channel_images/js/jquery.colorbox.js?v=6.0.2" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//your_site.com/themes/user/channel_images/js/jquery.editable.js?v=6.0.2" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//your_site.com/themes/user/channel_images/js/jquery.base64.js?v=6.0.2" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//your_site.com/themes/user/channel_images/js/jquery.liveurltitle.js?v=6.0.2" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//your_site.com/themes/user/channel_images/js/jquery.jcrop.js?v=6.0.2" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//your_site.com/themes/user/channel_images/js/swfupload.js?v=6.0.2" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//your_site.com/themes/user/channel_images/js/swfupload.queue.js?v=6.0.2" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//your_site.com/themes/user/channel_images/js/swfupload.speed.js?v=6.0.2" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//your_site.com/themes/user/channel_images/js/addon_pbf.js?v=6.0.2" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var SafeCracker = {}; SafeCracker.markItUpFields = EE.markItUpFields = {};
  });
  </script>
```

Best,

Ruslan